# Change of scalars in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, terminology

The question is about the use of change of scalars in algebraic geometry and I would like to keep it as concrete as possible to understand where and how it fits. So, let us fix the field extension $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$.

If $P(X_1,\dots,X_n) \in \mathbb{R}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ and $\mathbb{R}[X_1,\dots,X_n] / (P)$ is the corresponding coordinate ring, then extension of scalars to $\mathbb{C}$ (complexification) tells us to consider $\mathbb{C}[X_1,\dots,X_n] / (P)$ instead. Obviously, this makes a big difference, for example $\mathbb{R}[X] / (X^2 +1)$ vs. $\mathbb{C}[X] / (X^2 +1)$.

Now, instead of the above, start with $f(z_1,\dots,z_n) \in \mathbb{C}[z_1,\dots,z_n]$ and choose an $\mathbb{R}$-basis for $\mathbb{C}$, say $z_j =: x_j + iy_j$, $1\leq j \leq n$. Write $f(x_1 + i y_1,\dots,x_n + i y_n) =: u(x_1,y_1,\dots,x_n,y_n) + i v(x_1,y_1,\dots,x_n,y_n)$ for the real and imaginary parts of $f$. So, we have a map
$$
\mathbb{C}[z_1,\dots,z_n] \to \mathbb{R}[x_1,y_1,\dots,x_n,y_n] \otimes \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C}[x_1,y_1,\dots,x_n,y_n] \\
f \mapsto u + i v
$$

> (Q1) What is the relationship between the rings $\mathbb{C}[z_1,\dots,z_n]/(f)$ and $\mathbb{R}[x_1,y_1,\dots,x_n,y_n]/(u,v)$? Notice that one can instead go the other way around and start with a pair of polynomials $u,v$ satisfying the $\mathbb{C}$auchy-$\mathbb{R}$iemann differential equations.

> (Q2) What is the general mathematical context/terminology this comparison procedure fits in? ("Restriction" of scalars? "Change of basis"?) Notice that the choice $\mathbb{C} / \mathbb{R}$ is just for simplicity and this can be done in a much broader algebraic setting.

Comment: "Weil restriction" is the name for the second construction - see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_restriction), or [here on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3698975/) for instance.

Comment: @KReiser: thank you for the reply and the links!